# Why does ZStack only work in my ContentView?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a HomeView which is basically a ZStack of a MapView and a Circle, and I am following https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/advanced-mkmapview-with-swiftui.

Both the map and circle appear when I am using a ZStack right here in the ContentView.  However, I have authentication set up so when I do the following (below), I only see the map and not the circle:

ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var auth: AuthenticationState

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if auth.user != nil {
                HomeView()
            } else {
                GatekeeperView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HomeView.swift

```
struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .opacity(1)
                .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
            
            MapView().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}
```

Authenticated users get to see the HomeView.  Unfortunately, the circle does not show up.

Comment: Try explicitly setting `.zIndex()` for your views in `ZStack`

Comment: the circle is under the map view

Comment: thanks so much!  that works :D

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly setting `.zIndex()` for your views in `ZStack`:

```
struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .opacity(1)
                .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                .zIndex(1)

            MapView().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .zIndex(2)
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively reorder your `ZStack`:

```
struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            MapView().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            Circle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .opacity(1)
                .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
        }
    }
}
```